# How can I make the android program wait until two buttons are pressed?

Tags: java, android, button

I have a list of `buttons`, `b1, b2, etc..` each of which has an `onclick` method that adds a number to an `arraylist`.  I thought that adding the line

```
while(myArrayList.size()<2){}
```

Would make the program wait until two buttons were clicked, but instead the screen turns black. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this while loop on a different thread than the UI handler?

Comment: you should probably post your code

Comment: @hexafraction, I'm not sure how to tell.

Comment: It sounds like you are running the loop on your main/UI thread. It can't display the UI until the code is finished running, and it will never finish running until the UI is displayed so your user can click both buttons. In short, it sounds like an infinite loop that blocks the UI from ever showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the `while` loop on the UI thread, that's why your screen is not responding.
I'd say, check on your onClick method for the size of the array and then run when the condition is met, run the method you are waiting on. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.b1:
            list.add(someNumber);
            break;
        case R.id.b2:
            list.add(otherNumber);
            break;
    }
    if (list.size() == 2) {
        yourWaitingMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: what should be in waiting method?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that is your ArrayList is just initially empty and unless you have something in your while loop that adds elements to that ArrayList, then you'll stay stuck in that loop.

If you want to do something when two buttons are clicked, you could have two separate boolean variables that are each set to true once the button is clicked:

```
// boolean instance variables
boolean button1Clicked = false, button2Clicked = false;

...

// set the OnClickListeners
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button1Clicked = true;
        doSomething();
    }
});
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button2Clicked = true;
        doSomething();
    }
});

...

// the method to be called every time you click either button
private void doSomething(){
    if (button1Clicked && button2Clicked){ // but only executes what's inside here unless both buttons were clicked
        // do something
    }
}
```

Hope this helped!